# I can't connect to new router with same ssid

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

I have a problem with my wifi in Ubuntu (15.04). Recently, I have changed my wifi routers. Due to differents devices that was already configured, I have configured the new router with the same SSID and password, and this have worked for other devices but not for my Notebook with Ubuntu (in windows 7 in the same notebook it works!).

Intriguinly, If I change the SSID of my router network,  it works in Ubuntu, but i don't want to change my SSID, because i have a lot of devices with this ssid/password stored.

Why i can connect to my network except when the ssid is the same of my old network? I have tried remove the connection in network manager and create a new, but still doesn't work.

Please, How can i fix my problem?

Answer (score 3):

Delete the old connection and connect again. You will find your problem solved!

You can click on the Network Icon --> Edit Connections, this will let you delete previous Wireless or Wired configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. I don't know which step is really need, but it's what i have done, in order:

1. Remove wi-fi connections from network manager that has that ssid
   (i was tried create another one)
2. remove the files of that
   connections from /etc/NetworkManager/connections/[NAME OF
   CONNECTION]
3. reboot
4. login with the original admin user (i was
   trying with another admin user before)
5. Connect! Now works =)

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that the network collides with a non-host-only network Like I was facing the same issue because I was using IP: `192.168.10.10` for my virtual machine (through vagrant), and my network also had the same IP. So please change the IP or name of your host only network so that it no longer matches that of a bridged or non-host-only network.

I changed my virtual machine up to 192.168.20.10 and it works for me.